# Using Windows Icons in VB.net

Tags: vb.net

I am very new to VB and trying to create a app called shortcut manager on my own. 
I am trying to Figure out how to use default Icons(like Icon for word or notepad etc) of programs/applications in any of VB.net form? 
or 
Question is how to get the default icon for a program in vb?

I want them to be on the buttons(which I wil create to open the application) that I have created. So that it will launch that perticular app once I will click that button..

Thanks,

Comment: are you sure you are not able to do that??? I believe it is very easy if you are using VB IDE

Comment: Hello mlwn, I can create it but using background image option in vb on buttons.

Comment: So your question is how to get the default icon for a program? or you have the icon but don't know how to use it as the background of button?

Comment: Yes.. I will add this line in my question.. thanks..

Comment: @JBravo : 1) Do you know how to use API calls ? 2) Do you know how to dynamically define a button Image Property by using an icon ? (the icon instance in your application) 3) Do you knew that dynamically retrieving the associated icon for a given file sometimes returns an icon that has nothing to do with, therefore, you'll have to write an entire class (or module) to load ressources from dlls and exe ? (some 16bits exe) -> select something simple if you didn't knew, or have a lot of trials first.

Comment: @fsintegral, I am new to vb and exploring the possiblitied using online material. If you can let me know what I need to study for above topics I can look into it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I use this to get an application's icon:

```
Dim ico As Icon = System.Drawing.Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(<path here>)
```